# Is there a way to make text wrap in a bulleted list?

Tags: html, css

In the program I am currently working on, I have a bulleted list that adds items dynamically based on a textbox. My issue is that if the text entered is long and goes past the borders of the bulleted list it just keeps going. Is there any way for me to make the text wrap (go to the next line when it gets to the border), or is there a different approach to doing this? I tried looking online but could not find anything.

HTML For the bulleted list: `<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" BackColor="#3399FF" style="border: 7px outset rgb(176, 192, 222); border-image: none; left: 116px; top: 417px; width: 280px; height: 367px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; background-color: rgb(176, 196, 222);"></asp:BulletedList>`

The backend is just an array inside a for loop that makes a new item in the list for each index in the array.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what exact code you are using

Comment: Right, sorry about that. HTML:  `<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" BackColor="#3399FF" style="border: 7px outset rgb(176, 192, 222); border-image: none; left: 116px; top: 417px; width: 280px; height: 367px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; background-color: rgb(176, 196, 222);"></asp:BulletedList> `                    and in the backend (C#) it just has a for loop to add new items to the bulleted list

Comment: Just a simple example does wrap by default.

Comment: You should edit your question and add that code into the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `overflow-wrap` attribute in CSS ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)).

> The overflow-wrap CSS property specifies whether or not the browser
>   should insert line breaks within words to prevent text from
>   overflowing its content box.

`overflow-wrap: normal;`

Comment: This didn't work, it's almost as if it's not recognizing where the border is

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! In case anyone ever gets this issue, my solution was: word-wrap: normal; word-break: break-all; in the CSS.